# Math.Pow gives "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float' " error

Tags: c#, math, binary

In this program I am trying to create a simple calculator. However, I can't seem to find a way to overcome the aforementioned error when reaching the `Math.Pow` line.

```
namespace BinaryCalc
{
    class Binary
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

        int addition,subtraction;
        float division, multiplication, power, sqrt;

        int x;
        int y;
        x = 10;
        y = 7;

        //Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number for x");
        //string line = Console.ReadLine();
        //int x = int.Parse(line);

        //Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number for y");
        //string line2 = Console.ReadLine();
        //int y = int.Parse(line2);


        addition = (int)x + (int)y;
        subtraction = (int)x - (int)y;
        division = (float)x / (float)y;
        multiplication = (float)x * (float)y;

        power = Math.Pow(x,2);
        sqrt = Math.Sqrt(x);


        Console.WriteLine(" Addition results in {0}", addition);
        Console.WriteLine(" Subtraction results in {0}", subtraction);
        Console.WriteLine(" Division results in {0}", division);
        Console.WriteLine(" Multiplication results in {0}", multiplication);
        Console.WriteLine(" {0} squared results in {0}",x, power);
        Console.WriteLine(" Square root of {0} is: {0}", x, sqrt);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Math.Pow uses a `double` argument. As the error says, there is no *implicit* conversion from `double` to `float`, so convert the result *explicitly* to float:

```
power = (float)Math.Pow(x, 2);
```

**EDIT**
corrected the conversion order

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I actually already tried that but even though the error goes away, it gives me a wrong response. Same holds for the next line containing the square root.

Comment: The output in the console shows that the square root of 10 is 10, same number is given as a response for 10 to the power of 2.

Comment: @Alexandros: why can't you declare `power` and `sqrt` as double?

Comment: The problem isn't the argument but the return value - the error says there is no conversion from double to float, not float to double.

Comment: @alexandros: that's because you used `{0}` twice. The second should be `{1}`

Comment: `"{0} squared results in {0}"` prints the first argument twice. The math works, the format string is wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. This was indeed what was causing it. Quite silly of me.

Comment: In agreement with @Lee, it is not an issue with `Math.Pow()` but solely with the `=`. The second typecast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of `Math.Pow` is a `double`. The variable `power` in your program is a `float`, which has a smaller range and accuracy.

You should define `power` to be a `double`.

Comment: Or just case to `float`. If a programmer makes this mistake here without noticing the difference between float and double doesn't really matter at all, I guess.

Comment: @Joey: Casting to `float` opens the door to exceptions. If the OP requires that the end result fit into a `float` then this can be part of the solution, but not by itself. Additional "what to do if it doesn't fit" logic would be required.

Comment: Jon, what exceptions? If it doesn't fit it gets clamped at infinity or 0. Remember, we're talking floating-point here and not integer types. Also, look at the class the OP posted. You really expect them to try this with numbers around `1e200` instead of `25` or so?

Comment: @Joey: You are right about the exceptions (there will be none for this specific cast, as stated at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx). And I don't expect the OP to do that. But why use a solution with hidden gotchas when there is one with none?

Answer (score 1):

Use `double` instead of `float` for your variables.

The `float` data type has quite limited precision, so the rounding errors (that are always present in floating point arithmetics) are relatively large.

The reason that you see the wrong result of the square and square root, is that you never show the result at all. Change one of the `{0}` in each format string into `{1}`:

```
Console.WriteLine(" {0} squared results in {1}",x, power);
Console.WriteLine(" Square root of {0} is: {1}", x, sqrt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicitly casting the results of Math.Pow to float as such:

```
power = (float) Math.Pow(x, 2);
```

You can also use float's TryParse method to try and parse the result of Math.Pow:

```
float.TryParse(Math.Pow(x, 2).ToString(), out power);
```

Also, you might want to change the format string parameter numbers on the last two Console.WriteLine method calls. They should read like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(" {0} squared results in {1}",x, power);
Console.WriteLine(" Square root of {0} is: {1}", x, sqrt);
```

Comment: Going through a string with `TryParse` is nuts, definitely.

Comment: I can understand why you think the TryParse is less than optimal, but why the downvote as well? Aren't downvotes for incorrect and/or harmful responses? It is a valid answer to the problem (in combination with his error in the string formatting).